# Wordpress/Buddypress like count + number

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, buddypress

I am running wordpress/buddypress with the buddypress like plugin, basically I want to take the current number of 'likes' of the current post and add them with a number i choose.

for example:

if ( $liked_count == 0 ) change '$liked_count' to '$liked_count'+'NUMBER I CHOOSE'

so if the current like count of the post was 10 and i choose 5 as the +number, the like count would be 15.

is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_liked_count = $liked_count + 5
```